# Slider disabled on page on wordpress site. jQuery is also disabled on this page. What's the fastest way to figure out what's disabling it?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

On one of the websites we are working on a slider in the side column showing off the products is not appearing, although the code is there upon inspection. My superior told me something is disabling jQuery, as it's not disabled on the staging site and it's working fine. How can I figure out what is disabling it?

I have tried:

- changing plugin settings
- changing what the slider displays
- disabling certain plugins

Here's the script (although I don't think it's the actual problem)

```
<script>
var lsjQuery = jQuery;lsjQuery(document).ready(function() { if(typeof lsjQuery.fn.layerSlider == "undefined") { if( window._layerSlider && window._layerSlider.showNotice) { window._layerSlider.showNotice('layerslider_3','jquery'); } } else { lsjQuery("#layerslider_3").layerSlider({sliderVersion: '6.6.5', responsiveUnder: 0, layersContainer: 0, slideBGSize: 'auto', hideUnder: 0, hideOver: 100000, pauseOnHover: 1, skin: 'avada', showCircleTimer: false, thumbnailNavigation: 'disabled', skinsPath: 'https://www.aurawellnesscenter.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/ls-skins/'}); } });
</script>

<div id="layerslider_3" class="ls-wp-container fitvidsignore" style="width:275px;height:300px;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom: 0px;">
```

I don't think the problem is in the script itself, I think something is disabling it, probably another plugin. There must be some way to find out .

Comment: Hi, is there any error messages on the browser console? Apparently your html files are not import jQuery properly.

Comment: Yes there are errors. 3 of them.                                                                 (index):16 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):16
(index):2065 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):2065
(index):2072 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):2072
(index):2108 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):2108

Comment: All right. Go ahead and edit your question to add them. When jQuery is loaded, you should be able to type `$` into browser console and get a valid object.